# vb.net word document

Tags: vb.net

I can add a bullet in word document through vb.net by using applybulletDefault() method but how can i remove it in next line??

Answer (score 0):

Selection.Range.ListFormat.RemoveNumbers NumberType:=wdNumberParagraph will set you back to a normal paragraph.

When I'm writing VB code write to a Word Document I often use Record Macro in Word to do the actions as a user would, Stop Macro recording, Edit the macro, copy and paste into VB and massage we required.